# Unexpected Behavior Chaining Any() and None() in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What I'm trying to get is nodes having certain property values for any property name (key) and not having some other values for any property.

So in short, pseudo-google query be like:

```
+Tom +val1 +val2 (...) -Cruise -valX -valY (...)
```

and Cypher query be like:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE (
  ANY ( p in KEYS(n) WHERE n[p] CONTAINS 'Tom' ) AND
  NONE ( p in KEYS(n) WHERE n[p] CONTAINS 'Cruise')
)
RETURN n
```

But the test result with movie database (:play movie graph) was just an empty list, while there are other actors named 'Tom' in the database, such as Tom Hanks.
(match (n) where (any( p in KEYS(n) WHERE n[p] contains 'Tom')) return n
gives [Tom Tykwer, Tom Hanks, Tom Cruise, Tom Skerritt])

So I experimented with 'om' instead of 'Tom', and this time, the result is a incomplete list of 'om's:

```
match (n) where (
 any( p in KEYS(n) WHERE n[p] contains 'om') and 
 none( p in Keys(n) WHERE n[p] contains 'Cruise')
 )
 return n
```

gives

```
[Romantic (genre), Naomie Harris, James Thompson, Jessica Thompson]
(No Tom's -- why?)
```

Also tried NOT ANY() in place of NONE() and had same results.

Where does this inconsistency come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@stdob-- offers an accurate explanation of the issue.

But there are simpler workarounds. For instance, you can use the [COALESCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) function() to force a `NULL` value to be treated as `FALSE`:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE
  ANY ( p in KEYS(n) WHERE n[p] CONTAINS 'Tom' ) AND
  NONE( p in KEYS(n) WHERE COALESCE(n[p] CONTAINS 'Cruise', FALSE))
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that nodes have properties with a type other than `string`. And for them, NONE-verification gives `null`, which gives an error for `where` entirely. For example, this query return nothing:

```
WITH {k1: 1, k2: '2'} AS test 
WHERE NONE(key IN keys(test) WHERE test[key] CONTAINS '1')
RETURN test
```

So in this case you need to check the type of the property. Since there is no native type-checking function, you can use the function from the [`APOC library`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#meta-graph):

```
MATCH (n) WHERE (
  ANY(p in KEYS(n) WHERE apoc.meta.cypher.type(n[p]) = 'STRING' AND n[p] CONTAINS 'Tom') AND
  NONE(p in KEYS(n) WHERE apoc.meta.cypher.type(n[p]) = 'STRING' AND n[p] CONTAINS 'Cruise')
)
RETURN n
```